# How to write h-bar (Planck constant divided by 2 $\pi$) using MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3640822/284619) I wrote

$$|\mathbf{k_{scat}}| = \frac{2 \pi}{h}  \sqrt{2 m_e e V}$$

where $h$ is the [Planck constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant).

In physics we have h-bar which is $h/ 2 \pi$ but I don't know how to add h-bar using MathJax.

Comment: `\hbar` should produce $\hbar$.

Comment: @IvoTerek indeed it should, and does! I wonder if that could be added to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619) page somehow?

Comment: I just checked it quickly and it doesn't seem that this would fit with any of the current answers (and it doesn't warrant a new answer by itself). However, one of the answers does mention the Detexify website, where you can draw a symbol and they recognize what it is to give you the code. There is also a mobile app. I just made a sloppy h-bar on the mobile app and it was easily recognized.

Comment: @IvoTerek yay! https://i.stack.imgur.com/peJsY.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\hbar` produces $\hbar$ (as @IvoTerek has mentioned) and `\hslash` produces $\hslash$.

Generally, you could refer to [MathJax's docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/index.html) for LaTeX commands/symbols supported by MathJax and page 20-22 of [amsfonts' user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/amsfonts/doc/amsfndoc.pdf) for a list of symbols with their corresponding commands.